# How to work with arrays of space separated strings in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

I with to monitor if my access points pingable and store results into 0-1 string

I wrote a script but it works wrong

```
#/bin/bash

access_points=("tplink2" "redmi1")
#results=("A")
declare -a results

for val in "${access_points[@]}"
do
    ping -c 4 -w 10 $val 2>&1 >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
       online="+"
    else
       online="-"
    fi
    results[${#results[@]}]=$online
done
echo "${resutls[*]}"
echo $results
```

Why? Can I collect values not into arrays but into space separated strings?

Comment: `!` missing in the shebang.

Answer (score 3):

To add an element to an array, use `+=`:

```
results+=("$online")
```

Also note that `resutls` and `results` don't refer to the same variable.

BTW, you don't have to check `$?`, you can run the command directly in the `if`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

access_points=("tplink2" "redmi1")
declare -a results

for val in "${access_points[@]}"
do
    if ping -c 4 -w 10 "$val" 2>&1 >/dev/null
    then
       online="+"
    else
       online="-"
    fi
    results+=("$online")
done
echo "${results[@]}"
```

Comment: Can I start with `access_points="tplink2 redmi1"` somehow?

Comment: @Dims: You can, if the access points' names never contain whitespace. The loop will then have the form of `for val in $access_points`, i.e. no quotes. But why?